# Audio doesn't play on mobile safari even after user interaction

Tags: javascript, audio, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I am trying to write a small library for convenient manipulations with audio. I know about the autoplay policy for media elements, and I play audio after a user interaction:

```
const contextClass = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

const context = this.audioContext = new contextClass();

if (context.state === 'suspended') {
const clickCb = () => {
    this.playSoundsAfterInteraction();

    window.removeEventListener('touchend', clickCb);

    this.usingAudios.forEach((audio) => {
        if (audio.playAfterInteraction) {
            const promise = audio.play();

            if (promise !== undefined) {
                promise.then(_ => {

                }).catch(error => {
                    // If playing isn't allowed
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        }
    });
};

window.addEventListener('touchend', clickCb);
```

}

On android chrome everything ok and on a desktop browser. But on mobile Safari I am getting such error in promise:

**the request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context safari**

I have tried to create audios after an interaction, change their "src" property. In every case, I am getting this error.

I just create audio in js:

```
const audio = new Audio(base64);
```

add it to array and try to play. But nothing...
Tried to create and play after a few seconds after interaction - nothing.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this?